# what is the substitute for jquery's .animate() method in framework7?

Tags: jquery, html, html-framework-7

I am trying to implement a form which uses .animate() method for smooth scroll animation in framework7. Unfortunately it is not working. So can anyone suggest how to overcome this problem?

the relevant code snippet is as follows:

```
$('html, body').animate({               
  scrollTop: $("#nameDiv").offset().top
}, 1000);
```

Kindly help.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this with the Dom7 library:

```
$$('.page-content').scrollTo(0, $("#nameDiv").offset().top, 1000, function() {
    // do something on complete
});
```

You can find info about the .scrollTo() function in the Dom7 docs: https://framework7.io/docs/dom.html